# Converting CSV string to multiple columns in Apache Drill

Tags: csv, query-optimization, apache-drill, sqlline

Using: Apache Drill

I am trying to bring the following data in a more structured form:

```
"apple","juice", "box:12,shipment_id:143,pallet:B12" 
"mango", "pulp", "box:7,shipment_id:133,pallet:B19,route:11"
"grape", "jam", "box:10"
```

Desired output:

```
fruit, product, box_id, shipment_id, pallet_id, route_id
apple,juice, 12, 143, B12, null
mango, pulp, 7, 133, B19, 11
grape, jam, 10, null, null, null
```

Dataset runs into couple of GBs. Drill reads the input into three columns with the last string in one single column. Have successfully achieved the desired output by performing string manipulation operations (REGEXP_REPLACE and CONCAT) on the last column, then reading the column as json (CONVERT_FROM), and finally separating into different columns using KVGEN and FLATTEN.

The execution time is pretty high due to the regex functions. Is there a better approach?

(PS: execution time is compared to using a pyspark job to achieve the desired output).

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any other way to do it 100% with Apache Drill, without any intermediate storage

You may try with a Custom Function in Java, to make it easier to write.

Since you have done the work, 
have you tried to save the data in a Parquet file? CTAS command: http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas-command/

This would make subsequent queries a lot faster.